# Using Java jsoup to parse a html page and store data

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to use jsoup libraries to parse a html file and get all the data relating to `table class="scl_list"` as below, which is only a small part of the html page.

```
<table class="scl_list">
        <tr>
            <th align="center">Id:</th>
            <th align="center">Name:</th>
            <th align="center">Serial:</th>
            <th align="center">Status:</th>
            <th align="center">Ladestrom:</th>
            <th align="center">Z&auml;hleradresse:</th>
            <th align="center">Z&auml;hlerstand:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="center">7</th>
            <th align="center">7</th>
            <th align="center">c3001c0020333347156a66</th>
            <th align="center">Idle</th>
            <th align="center">16.0</th>
            <th align="center">40100021</th>
            <th align="center">12464.25</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="center">21</th>
            <th align="center">21</th>
            <th align="center">c3002a003c343551086869</th>
            <th align="center">Idle</th>
            <th align="center">16.0</th>
            <th align="center">540100371</th>
            <th align="center">1219.73</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

For every `<tr>` , I then need to get every `<th>` and save the data in a table or vector. Unfortunately I can't find many examples using jsoup which does something similar.

So far I have this, where `html_string` is my html page, but I'm not sure how to progress. Any help is much appreciated :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html_string);
Elements els = doc.getElementsContainingText("table class=\"scl_list\"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is a simple and intuitive library. You can find many examples online how to read html tables. Look at the documentation under [jsoup cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/) and especially the [selector-syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). To get back to your question, an easy way would be the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html =   "<table class=\"scl_list\">\n" +
                    "        <tr>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Id:</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Name:</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Serial:</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Status:</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Ladestrom:</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Z&auml;hleradresse:</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Z&auml;hlerstand:</th>\n" +
                    "        </tr>\n" +
                    "        <tr>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">7</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">7</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">c3001c0020333347156a66</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Idle</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">16.0</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">40100021</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">12464.25</th>\n" +
                    "        </tr>\n" +
                    "        <tr>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">21</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">21</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">c3002a003c343551086869</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">Idle</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">16.0</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">540100371</th>\n" +
                    "            <th align=\"center\">1219.73</th>\n" +
                    "        </tr>\n" +
                    "    </table>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements trs = doc.select("table.scl_list tr");
    List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Element tr : trs){
        List<String> row = tr.select("th").stream().map(e -> e.text())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        data.add(row);
    }
    data.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The output should be something like:

```
[Id:, Name:, Serial:, Status:, Ladestrom:, Zähleradresse:, Zählerstand:]
[7, 7, c3001c0020333347156a66, Idle, 16.0, 40100021, 12464.25]
[21, 21, c3002a003c343551086869, Idle, 16.0, 540100371, 1219.73]
```

Since the first element seems to contain only the table heading, you can skip it by using a simple for loop and starting from the second element.

Since I assume that your data represents electricity meters, I would recommend you to implement a small class as data container, which could look like this

```
class Meter{
    int id;
    String name;
    String serial;
    String status;
    double chargingCurrent;
    String address;
    double  meterReading;

    public Meter(List<String> data) {
        this.id = Integer.parseInt(data.get(0));
        this.name = data.get(1);            
        this.serial = data.get(2);
        this.status = data.get(3);
        this.chargingCurrent = Double.parseDouble(data.get(4));
        this.address = data.get(5);
        this.meterReading = Double.parseDouble(data.get(6));
    }
    // getters & setters
}
```

The code from above could then be rewrittten to something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements trs = doc.select("table.scl_list tr");
List<Meter> meters = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1; i< trs.size(); i++){
    List<String> row = trs.get(i).select("th").stream().map(e -> e.text())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    meters.add(new Meter(row));
} 
meters.forEach(System.out::println);
```

with a corresponding `toString` method the output will look like:

```
Meter{id=7, name=7, serial=c3001c0020333347156a66, status=Idle, chargingCurrent=16.0, address=40100021, meterReading=12464.25}
Meter{id=21, name=21, serial=c3002a003c343551086869, status=Idle, chargingCurrent=16.0, address=540100371, meterReading=1219.73}
```